# Change in source :Agents per arrival and Maximum number of arrival at runtime

Tags: anylogic

I am modeling a manufacturing system. The case is that I would like to implement a ramp-up model so the Agents per arrival and Maximum number of arrival change at a specific time during the simulation.
I tried to implement this by using an event but then I am not able to actually change the values of the source.

[image: Picture of the properties of the source]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your source arrivals to be defined by calls of inject() funtion.

Use a cyclic event with a reccurence time of 1. That will reflect your interarrival time.

Then use an if statement to control your maximum arrivals.

```
if (source.count() < maxArrivals) {

  source.inject(agentsPerArrival);

}
```

Comment: It depends on what `maxArrivals` represents, but it might need to be `source.countArrivals()` instead of `source.count()` if we need the same functionality as Maximum number of arrivals.

Comment: maxArrivals in this case would be `145/towerRatio` as shown in the image added to the question. This should be rounded to `int` preferably. And you're right about the source.countArrivals(). Depends on what he wants to limit, number of agents or number arrivals. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Maximum number of arrivals is a static parameter, you can't change it during runtime like that. (Check out the icons in front of the edit boxes: `Agents per arrival` has an arrow, showing that it's dynamic and `Maximum number of arivals` has an equal sign)

You can call `towerFactory.set_maxArrivals(145/towerRatio)` in your event, but it will only take effect if the Source has not reached the previously set number of arrivals yet. If that is the case, you need to take a different approach.